# The path in 'value' must start with '/'. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I am creating a chat component for my ASP.NET Core 2 application. I want to use SignalR for it. The current version of SignalR is 1.0.0-preview2-final.

I am following the steps from this article, which is using an older version of the library:
https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-signalr-simple-chat/

My SignalR code in the **Startup.cs**:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<Chat>("chat");
});
```

I followed the article and when I tried to run the application, I got this error:

> The path in 'value' must start with '/'. Parameter name: value

[image: stacktrace and error log]

Any idea on how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add "/" before the name of the hub.

Something like this:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<Chat>("/chat");
});
```